# How to populate a column in a dataframe based on data in another column and condition /switch on another column in python

Tags: python, pandas

so i have a dataframe that i created by reading a csv. it has following columns:
[the columns in csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgD1I.png). Now i need to populate the vol column. the volume for different tree species has already been calculated. the logic goes like this
if specie is acacia, the diameter in "dbh"(diameter at breast height) column is 15, the volume is 15.9  and so on for other species.
i have tried if else statement but that throws error that the values are ambigous. then i tried this

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv("location in my pc")
df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
wdf = pandas.DataFrame(df[["site", "avkmrd", "sno", "specie", "dbh", "vol", "remarks"]])
wdf["dbh"] = (wdf["dbh"] / 2.54).__round__(0) #convert cm to inches
#key is diameter, value is volume(timber)
acaciavt = {3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 2.96, 9: 4.48, 10: 6.27, 11: 8.35, 12: 10.7, 13: 13.1, 14: 16.1, 15: 18.9,16: 22.6, 17: 26, 18: 29, 19: 32.9, 20: 36.3, 21: 40.6, 22: 44.2, 23: 48, 24: 53, 25: 57, 26: 61.1, 27: 66.7, 28: 71.1, 29: 75.5, 30: 80} 
    
    
wdf['vol'] = wdf.loc[wdf['specie'] == 'acacia', wdf["dbh"].map(acaciavt)]
```

returns error

```
error:  raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([51.1, 39.6, 51.1, 34.5,  0.0, 29.8, 34.5, 14.1, 45.1, 21.1,\n              ...\n              17.7, 21.1, 34.5, 39.6,  nan, 17.7, 21.1, 17.7, 17.7,  0.0],\n             dtype='float64', length=1092)] are in the [columns]"
```

please note that as you can see in the image i upload, there are different species, then there are random dbh, and their volumes depends on species and dbh. i would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have different dictionaries for each species, you would have to do something similar to the following for each species:

```
wdf["vol"] = wdf[wdf["specie"]=="acacia"]["dbh"].apply(lambda x: acaciavt[int(x)] if not pd.isnull(x) else None)
```

Let me break the code by bit and explain what is happening:

1. Filter the dataframe to get rows where "specie" is "acacia":

```
wdf[wdf["specie"]=="acacia"]`
```

2. Select only the `dbh` column from the above:

```
wdf[wdf["specie"]=="acacia"]["dbh"]
```

3. To each value of this filtered dataframe, i.e., to each `dbh` value, we `apply` a function that returns the value of the `dbh` from the `acaciavt` dictionary. Since the value could be a `float`, we first convert it to `int`:

```
.apply(lamba x: acaciavt[int(x)])
```

As an aside, you can make your code a little bit "neater" by using the following instead of your first few lines:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("location in my pc")
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
wdf = df[["site", "avkmrd", "sno", "specie", "dbh", "vol", "remarks"]]
wdf["dbh"] = (wdf["dbh"]/2.54).round(0)
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. i am in forestry, i have just started to code. this one returns this error..... ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: Your `dbh` column for certain values are empty? In this case, what should the `vol` be?

Comment: I edited my answer a bit to handle empty values. Now, if one of the rows has an empty (`np.nan`) value for `dbh`, the corresponding `vol` would be an empty (`None`) value.

Comment: oh my God. thank you. now it works. Thank you so much. Thank you so much. i ve been stuck since days. can you please tell how it works? and do i repeat the same for all the other species

Comment: there was an empty dbh at tree no 89654th in the column :( i am sorry

Comment: I tried to breakdown my answer and explain bit by bit but you may want to look up implementation of `lambda` functions :)

Comment: thanks. i have upvoted but since i am at 1. i ll surely upvote once i get to 15

Comment: Please don’t worry about that. Enjoy your coding journey!